# Unable to figure out how to pass multiple View IDs - Google Analytics

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I would like to pass multiple view ids as my view ids are territories and combine them together into a single dataframe. Can somebody help me out as I'm a begineer.

I have tried the below for loop but not sure.
IDs = ['156950826','156928279','156964042']

```
def ga_data(i):
    IDs = i 
    return
```

Below is the code to get it batch wise/

```
def get_report(analytics):
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': [{'VIEW_ID':i} for i in VIEW_ID],
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': START_DATE, 'endDate': END_DATE}],
          'metrics': [{'expression':i} for i in METRICS],
          'dimensions': [{'name':j} for j in DIMENSIONS],
          'pageSize': 8000 #by default batch request gives only 1000 results. Max is 100,000
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant the [View id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest) in a report request is singular.  You can only send one view id per report.

As far as batching goes.

> Requests, each request will have a separate response. There can be a maximum of 5 requests. All requests should have the same dateRanges, viewId, segments, samplingLevel, and cohortGroup.

If you want to make a request across different views you need to send different requests

Just create a loop in your python code to make tadeonal requests against the api.